# Google Earth KML Autoload/Distribution

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-pro, deployment

Situation:

We have installed Google Earth on the whole computer network.
We have one KML with all our projects.

Need:

Distribute the KML on all those Google Earth instances.

Requirements:

-Distribution of the KML through a Networklink object for easy updating.

-Batch update all those computers with that networklink.

-The networklink should be placed in the my places section.

Possible solutions:

-Commandline -> as far as I know there are no commandline parameters?

-Relocate the directory where myplaces.kml is stored to a writeable central location? -> Users are users, this would quickly degrade myplaces.kml to a junkyard.

-Relocate the directory where myplaces.kml is stored to a read only central location? -> This would degrade Google Earth as a viewer? Or only as a editor in temporary places?

Are there any other options or remarks on the options researched?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but I set up something similarly a while back.

Users pointed to a network link that was updated via [FME](https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/), which fed from our GIS and SAP databases. We came up with the designation that all edits must be performed in a system of record (GIS or SAP) and an FME script would run twice daily to push those updates to the network link.

Google Earth users were viewers only.

Deployment was easy enough. All the end users had to do was click on a kml link in an email that they received and then save it in their places when they closed GE. If they didn't save, it was easy enough for them to reopen the email link, since it never changed.